# What does this perl crash means?

Tags: perl

Can someone tell me what this means?

```
if (not defined $config{'crontab'}) {
  die "no crontab defined!";
}
```

I want to open a file crontab.txt but the perl script crashes at this line and I don't really know any perl.

---

EDIT 1

It goes like this:

```
sub main()
{
    my %config = %{getCommandLineOptions()};
    my $programdir = File::Spec->canonpath (    (fileparse ( Win32::GetFullPathName($PROGRAM_NAME) ))[1] );
    my $logdir = File::Spec->catdir ($programdir, 'logs');
    $logfile = File::Spec->catfile ($logdir, 'cronw.log');

    configureLogger($logfile);
    $log = get_logger("cronw::cronService-pl");

    # if --exec option supplied, we are being invoked to execute a job
    if ($config{exec}) {
        execJob(decodeArgs($config{exec}), decodeArgs($config{args}));
        return;
    }

    my $cronfile = $config{'crontab'};

    $log->info('starting service');
    $log->debug('programdir: '.$programdir);
    $log->debug('logfile: '.$logfile);
    if (not defined $config{'crontab'}) {
        $log->error("no crontab defined!\n");
        die "no crontab defined!";
        # fixme: crontab detection?
    }
    $log->debug('crontab: '.$config{'crontab'});
```

And I'm trying to load this 'crontab.txt' file...

---

```
sub getCommandLineOptions()
{
my $clParser = new Getopt::Long::Parser config => ["gnu_getopt", "pass_through"];
my %config = ();
my @parameter = (   'crontab|cronfile=s',
    'exec=s',
    'args=s',
    'v|verbose'
                          );

$clParser->getoptions (\%config, @parameter);
if (scalar (@ARGV) != 0)  { $config{'unknownParameter'} = $true; }

return \%config;
}
```

Probably I have to give the script an argument

Comment: "no crontab defined! at cronService.pl line 410."

Comment: Your code calls something named `getCommandLineOptions()` and assigns that to `%config`. That name strongly hints that perhaps your missing `crontab` setting is related to some command line argument that you are expected to supply.

Comment: I believe you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Probably I have to give the script an argument

I would say so.

`$ script --cronfile=somefile`

Answer (score 2):

That code looks to see whether there is a key `'crontab'` in the hash `%config`. If not, then it calls `die` and terminates.

If that's not what you *expect* to happen, then somewhere else in your script there should be something that is setting `$config{'crontab'}`, but there is not currently enough information in your question to determine what that might be.

Comment: I think this is it, but as perl is like Klingon to me... I just want to tell the script where to find the file 'crontab.txt'

Comment: Well, you could add a line `$config{'crontab'} = "/path/to/crontab.txt";` before that code and see if that helps.

Comment: my $cronfile = $config{'crontab'};

Answer (score 1):

Probably the file path of crontab.txt is expected in %config hash, pointed by the 'crontab' key, but isn't there! If so, a DIRTY solution CAN BE:

```
$config{'crontab'}='FULLPATH/crontab.txt';
#if (not defined $config{'crontab'}) {
#   die "no crontab defined!";
#}
```

but this may not work because there is something like $config{'prefix'} and what you will try to open is the path represented by the concatenation of both, or just because in $config{'crontab'} is expected any other value than full path!